# iAd Doesn't Animate Ad Appearance

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I'm implementing iAd in my app using the paradigms for a multi-VC app that apple demonstrates in their sample code (e.g. TabbedBanner and NavigationBanner). If you're not familiar with it, the paradigm is essentially to have the main app delegate serve as the primary AdBannerViewDelegate, and share the banner view across your respective view controllers.

My ads are appearing fine throughout the app, without any warnings. The problem is that for some reason when I click an ad banner, it doesn't navigate the appearance of the ad (should slide up from the bottom). There's just a delay and then the ad appears. But when I dismiss the ad it animates fine.

The appearance animates fine in apple's sample code, so the problem lies somewhere in my code. I'm just not sure where because I haven't changed much in the iAd implementation. My `bannerViewActionShouldBegin` is just

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:BannerViewActionWillBegin object:self];
    return YES;
}
```

But I don't think the problem lies in the NotificationCenter, because if I comment out that bit and just do

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    return YES;
}
```

The problem remains.

Any ideas? I can post more code, but my digging around in the documentation hasn't revealed anything that would flip an `animated` BOOL for ad presentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, the best I could figure is that this seems to simply be an iOS version issue. In 4.0 it fails to animate. In 5.0 it animates.